# Android floating label effect no working on TextInputLayout using databinding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

The hint wont float if u set it using data binding

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/inputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:theme="@style/TextAppearance.TextInputLayout.Form"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usernameEditTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_margin_3"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="@{model.label}"
        android:inputType="none"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

But if u set the hint manually, it works.
Im using Android Studio 3.0
Also using kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.3"

Anyone solved this one?

Comment: I had the same problem. here is how I fix it https://stackoverflow.com/a/46731803/1930468

Comment: You can refer to this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967669/float-label-hint-textinputlayout-not-works-with-android-data-binding/46731803#46731803. This solution works well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `hint` attribute on the `TextInputLayout`.

With Material Components:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
      android:hint="@{viewModel.textHint}"
```

with old support library:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
     android:hint="@{....}"
```

The reason is that `TextInputLayout` reads the hint attribute from the `TextInputEditText` only once (if not specified). After the inflation the changes on the `TextInputEditText` don't change the `TextInputLayout`'s hint.
With the databinding on the `TextInputEditText` you are not updating the `TextInputLayout` for the same reason.